# Rollback Microsoft Defender Virus Definitions to Previous or Specific Version

Tags: windows, windows-defender

Is there a method via the Graph/Defender API to rollback antivirus definitions to a previous or specific version?

Answer (score 1):

Not using the graph api. The Defender updates are windows updates on the client.
So maybe with a PowerShell script to uninstall the update (Security Intelligence)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/microsoft-defender-antivirus-updates?view=o365-worldwide#how-to-roll-back-an-update

To roll back to the previous version, run the following command:

```
"%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\<version>\MpCmdRun.exe" -RevertPlatform
```

To roll back this update to the version shipped with the Operating System ("%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender")

```
"%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\<version>\MpCmdRun.exe" -ResetPlatform
```